# How to open files on my desktop using C# Net.Core script?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to make a link in C# Net Core? And whenever the user types in the user input command window to open a certain file on my PC?

Like for example:

```
Console.Write("Open project?: ");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();

If (answer == "yes")
{
 //Open file cmd here, and one linked file for example.
}
```

Comment: Could you clear more what you try to do ?...are you mean file to proces with your prgram or run others application like notpad.exe see [run some other programs from c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43a76b19-db17-43bb-ba05-57675ff23a3c/how-to-run-some-other-programs-from-c-program?forum=csharplanguage)

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a file or program programmatically, you firs have to know the location of that file then be sure that such file is on disk otherwise if you try to open it, it throws an error.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

Console.Write("Open project?: ");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();

If (answer == "yes")
{
 try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nOpening file from your documents folder....");
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\myfile.txt";

            Process.Start(path);
            //Or a program
            Process.Start("notepad.exe");
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
}
```